# 2 equalities on an IF conditional like in python

Tags: javascript, python, if-statement, while-loop, triple-equals

I'm starting to learn javascript for front-end programming, being python my first language to learn completely.

So I'm trying to solve a while loop excersise that console-logs every number from 50-300 that is divisble by 5 and 3.

So in python i would do this:

```
i = 50
while i < 301:
    if i % 5 == i % 3 == 0:
        print(i)
    i += 1
```

And works flawlessly. I know you could use and `and` operator but the whole point of this question is to avoid using it.

So I try the same thing in javascript

```
var i = 50;
while (i < 301){
    if (i % 5 === i % 3 === 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
    i ++;
}
```

And somehow that wont work. However, with an `&&` operator it does. Are double equalities in javascript not allowed? If they are, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *allowed*, and it does exactly what you told it to do -- it's just that that's not the same as what you *want* it to do. `i % 5 === i % 3 === 0` is the same as `(i % 5 === i % 3) === 0` (because `===` is left-associative). `(i % 5 === i % 3)` evaluates to either `true` or `false` depending on the value of `i`, and `true === 0` and `false === 0` are both false, so the condition will always be false.

Comment: I would venture to say double equalities are _not_ allowed. You can still write the conditional `3==5==0` but that will not be a proper double inequality